# How to display an array result to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am grouping a set of items by Date in this example, I want the return "groupArrays" to be displayed in an html.

Firstly, group ids must be created for each date or date can be used as group id then the list of games for the dates should be listed under the date as shown in the output below. thanks in advance.

I expect the output of

```
<div id="items"><div id="group-1"> 
 <div class="Date">2017-10-04</div>        
 <ul class="Games">  
<li game_id="1">notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T20:24:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'steve', players: '10', game_id: 1</li>    
<li game_id="2">notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T12:35:30+00:00', sport: 'lacrosse', owner: 'steve', players: '6', game_id: 2</li>   
  <li game_id="4">notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T10:12:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'henry', players: '10', game_id: 4</li>           
 </ul>
 </div> 
 <div id="group-2"> 
 <div class="Date">2017-10-14</div>        
 <ul class="Games">  
<li game_id="3">notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-14T20:32:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'steve', players: '4', game_id: 3</li>    
<li game_id="5">notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-14T20:34:30+00:00', sport: 'soccer', owner: 'john', players: '12', game_id: 5 </li>          
 </ul>
   </div>         
      </div>
```

```js
const data = [
      {notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T20:24:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'steve', players: '10', game_id: 1},
      { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T12:35:30+00:00', sport: 'lacrosse', owner: 'steve', players: '6', game_id: 2 },
      { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-14T20:32:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'steve', players: '4', game_id: 3 },
      { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T10:12:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'henry', players: '10', game_id: 4 },
      { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-14T20:34:30+00:00', sport: 'soccer', owner: 'john', players: '12', game_id: 5 }
    ];

// this gives an object with dates as keys
    const groups = data.reduce((groups, game) => {
      const date = game.time.split('T')[0];
      if (!groups[date]) {
        groups[date] = [];
      }
      groups[date].push(game);
      return groups;
    }, {});

// Edit: to add it in the array format instead
const groupArrays = Object.keys(groups).map((date) => {
  return {
    date,
    games: groups[date]
  };
});

console.log(groupArrays);
```

Comment: Please add expected output

Comment: can you please show the output

Comment: what are you getting in console.log?

Comment: @mplungjan kindly find expected output

Comment: @AmiteshKumar kindly find expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the the answer hope it may helps you :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Loopin through an array using a for loop:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var date = '';
const data = [
          {notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T20:24:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'steve', players: '10', game_id: 1},
          { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T12:35:30+00:00', sport: 'lacrosse', owner: 'steve', players: '6', game_id: 2 },
          { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-14T20:32:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'steve', players: '4', game_id: 3 },
          { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T10:12:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'henry', players: '10', game_id: 4 },
          { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-14T20:34:30+00:00', sport: 'soccer', owner: 'john', players: '12', game_id: 5 }
        ];

    // this gives an object with dates as keys
        const groups = data.reduce((groups, game) => {
          const date = game.time.split('T')[0];
          if (!groups[date]) {
            groups[date] = [];
          }
          groups[date].push(game);
          return groups;
        }, {});

    // Edit: to add it in the array format instead
    const groupArrays = Object.keys(groups).map((date) => {
      return {
        date,
        games: groups[date]
      };
    });

    console.log(groupArrays);

for (i = 0; i < groupArrays.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < groupArrays[i].games.length; j++) {
        console.log(groupArrays[i].games[j]);
      date += "<br>date: "+ groupArrays[i].date + "<br> Games: " +      "<br> Notes:  " + groupArrays[i].games[j].notes + "<br> Sport:  " + groupArrays[i].games[j].sport
     + "<br> Owner:  " + groupArrays[i].games[j].owner 
      + "<br> Players:  " + groupArrays[i].games[j].players 
      +"<br> Game ID:  " + groupArrays[i].games[j].game_id

      + "<br> "
    }

}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Js Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/6unq0s1r/)

Modified Answer :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Loopin through an array using a for loop:</p>

<p id="demo">
    <ul id="myList">
     </ul>
</p>

<script>
var date = '';
var date_val = '';
const data = [
          {notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T20:24:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'steve', players: '10', game_id: 1},
          { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T12:35:30+00:00', sport: 'lacrosse', owner: 'steve', players: '6', game_id: 2 },
          { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-14T20:32:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'steve', players: '4', game_id: 3 },
          { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-04T10:12:30+00:00', sport: 'hockey', owner: 'henry', players: '10', game_id: 4 },
          { notes: 'Game was played', time: '2017-10-14T20:34:30+00:00', sport: 'soccer', owner: 'john', players: '12', game_id: 5 }
        ];

    // this gives an object with dates as keys
        const groups = data.reduce((groups, game) => {
          const date = game.time.split('T')[0];
          if (!groups[date]) {
            groups[date] = [];
          }
          groups[date].push(game);
          return groups;
        }, {});

    // Edit: to add it in the array format instead
    const groupArrays = Object.keys(groups).map((date) => {
      return {
        date,
        games: groups[date]
      };
    });

    console.log(groupArrays);

for (i = 0; i < groupArrays.length; i++) {
     date = groupArrays[i].date;
      var para = document.createElement("P");                       
      var t = document.createTextNode(date);      
      para.appendChild(t);                                        
      document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(para);
    var ul = document.createElement("UL");
    for (j = 0; j < groupArrays[i].games.length; j++) {

        console.log(groupArrays[i].games[j]);

        date_val =     " Notes:  " + groupArrays[i].games[j].notes + ", Sport:  " + groupArrays[i].games[j].sport
     + ", Owner:  " + groupArrays[i].games[j].owner 
      + ",Players:  " + groupArrays[i].games[j].players 
      +",Game ID:  " + groupArrays[i].games[j].game_id

      + " ";
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(date_val);

       var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.setAttribute('class','item');

            ul.appendChild(li);

            li.innerHTML=li.innerHTML + date_val;
      ul.appendChild(li);



    }
         document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(ul);


}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Modifed answer fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/0s27o1a3/)

Comment: thanks for the reply, i need the games to be grouped under the dates. please see expected output.

Comment: Hi please check now i add one more code in the answer.

Comment: Please guide me to understand how you divide array list in 3:2?

Comment: If you see the code groupArrays is a two dimensional  array , show i used two nested loops one for date and another for sports, in outer loop i created a P tag for date and in inner loop i created Ul and li tag  to store remaining information. Check the code and try to dry run you will understand .

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function where you get the data

```
 for (i = 0, len = groupArrays.length"; i < len; i++) {    
     var obj= document.getElementById('dateId');
      obj.innerHTML += groupArrays[i].date 
       var obj2= document.getElementById('gameId');
      obj2.innerHTML += groupArrays[i].game  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var fruitsArray = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango", "Pineapple"];
  $.each(fruitsArray, function(index, value){
    $(".result-1").append(index + ": " + value + '<br>');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  var supercarObject = {"brand": "Lamborghini", "model" : "Huracan", "origin": "Italy"};
  $.each(supercarObject, function(key, value){
    $(".result-2").append(key + ": " + value + '<br>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='results'>
     <p>Below the result only array value with index value</p>
     <div class="result-1"></div>
</div>
<p>=====================</p>
<div class='results'>
      <p>Below the result only array value with key value </p>
      <div class="result-2"></div>
</div>
<p>========================================</p>
<p>OR you can check abnother query:</p>
<a href='https://codepen.io/santanup789/details/zVxPEe'>Get values from fields in an array and print those values</a>
```

Comment: kindly find expected output

Comment: You want show the detailed info all games of a single day.. am i right?